# RegEx: Find first appearance inside quotes

Tags: regex

I have such multi line text:

```
sometext "F1" "some other text;" "some other text;"
sometext "1" "some other text;"
sometext "`" "some other text;"
sometext "Tab" "some other text;"
sometext "CapsLock" "some other text;" "some other text;"
sometext "Shift" "some other text;"
sometext "\" "some other text;"
sometext "K" "some other text;"
sometext "ins" "some other text;"
sometext "downarrow" "some other text;" "some other text;"
sometext "Num Lock" "some other text;"
sometext "num5" "some other text;"
sometext "numenter" "some other text;"
```

I need to get value inside first quotes within each line.
I've tried `"(.*?)"` but it finds each value inside "".

Answer (score 1):

To get the value inside the first occurance of the double quotes, you could add an anchor to assert the start of the line `^` and then match not a " using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^"]*`. Your match will be in the first capturing group:

[`^[^"]*"(.*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/2gFetj/1)

Or you could also use a negated character class to capture what is between the double quotes:

[`^[^"]*"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/2gFetj/3)

Comment: Thanks for an answer but your solution matches only very first value inside first brackets. I need to match first value within each line. So the output would be F1, 1, `, Tab, CapsLock etc.

Comment: @PjotrsSokolovs In the examples I use the global and the  multiline flag. Which tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: Yes, with global and multi line flags it works. Thank you

Comment: I'm using JS and your solution also marks the whole text before first " appears.

Comment: Your value is in the first capturing group. If you hover a match you see group #1: F1. If you look at it on regex101 [`^[^"]*"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/2gFetj/3) you see that the first group is highlighted.

Comment: This fiddle is a javascript example using the first capturing group: https://jsfiddle.net/kh5ryzvL/

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote by using a backslash `\"`

try 
`\"(.*?)\"`